# How to use a fq in solrconfig.xml 's requestHandler

Tags: solr, requesthandler

I am trying to setup my requestHandler on my `solrconfig.xml` file to use a fq. So here is my code:

```
<requestHandler name="/safe" class="com.orestis.custom.solr.handlers.SafeSearchRequestHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
       <int name="rows">1</int>
       <str name="fl">bookPrice,bookCode,bookAuthor,bookPublishDate</str>
       <str name="fq">bookPublishDate</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="sort">bookPrice asc</str>
    </lst>

    <lst name="variants">
       <str name="q">*:*</str>
       <str name="printParams">all</str>
    </lst>

    <lst name="allowed">
       <str name="q" />
       <str name="fq" />
       <str name="rows" />
       <str name="wt" />
       <str name="indent" />
       <str name="fl"/>
       <str name="sort"/>
       <str name="sfield"/>
       <str name="pt"/>
       <str name="group"/>
       <str name="group.field"/>
       <str name="group.main"/>
       <str name="group.limit"/>
       <str name="group.sort"/>
       <str name="group.query"/>
       <str name="echoParams"/>
    </lst>  

    <lst name="minMaxList">
       <str name="rows">1,3</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

The thing is that when I try to visit:
`http://solr.mysite.com/solr/BookStore/safe?q=fl=bookPrice,bookCode,bookAuthor,bookPublishDate&fq=bookPublishDate:[NOW/HOUR%2B6HOURS%20TO%20*]` on my browser I get this:

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":448,"params":{"printParams":"all","fl":"bookPrice,bookCode,bookAuthor,bookPublishDate","sort":"bookPrice asc","q":["*:*","*:*"],"wt":"json","fq":["bookPublishDate:[NOW/HOUR+6HOURS TO *]","bookPublishDate:[NOW/HOUR+6HOURS TO *]"],"rows":"1"}}...response continues
```

Any thoughts why I get the `"bookPublishDate:[NOW/HOUR+6HOURS TO *]"` twice on the response?

Comment: Could there be something in `com.orestis.custom.solr.handlers.SafeSearchRequestHandler` that is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

q=fl=bookPrice,bookCode,bookAuthor,bookPublishDate looks wrong to me.

Try `http://solr.mysite.com/solr/BookStore/safe?q=*:*&fq=bookPublishDate:\[NOW/HOUR%2B6HOURS%20TO%20*\]`

Comment: Yes it didnt look right without the "*:*&" part but even using that didnt make any difference. I got back the same response.